# PDF Mod extract

Tags: pdf

Having PDF Mod,I extracted a file(70 mb) into 6 pieces.Now,in each piece when I go to properties I still see 70mb when each of them is about 11-13mb.How can I change that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have a 70MB pdf with 6 pages, being so big I believe you have high density images inside.

I know two options `imagemagick` or `ghostscript`, you'll lose quality with both so check the result before you dispose of the original.

1. Imagemagick: `convert -density 300 Original.pdf -resample 150 -quality 80 -compress JPEG Result.pdf`. `-density` represents the original image density in dpi, `-resample` result density, `-quality` JPEG quality in %.
2. GhostScript: `gs -o Result.pdf -r150 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite Original.pdf`. `-r` result density.